# Convert array string objects to floats

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Longtime lurker (but still majorly sucky programmer) here. I've looked around for the answer to this and couldn't find any.

I'm trying to read an array from a plist, and then turn those objects from strings to floats.

The code that I'm trying right now declares an `NSNumberFormatter`, and tries to read in and convert to a float there. It's not working, the `NSLog` always shows a 0 for those values.

Here's my code that I'm using to (successfully) read-in the array from `Plist`, and (not successfully) convert its strings to floats:

```
//Find the Plist and read in the array:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath =  [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
//Working up til here, the NSLog correctly shows the values of the array
NSArray *fileArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

//Turn object in array from string to float
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *readinVol = [format numberFromString: fileArray [0]]; 
//This line not working, I believe- intended to read-in as an NSNumber, 
//and then convert to float below:
CGFloat readVol = [readinVol floatValue] * _volFloat;
```

So my question is:

How can I turn my objects stored in the array from their current strings into more usable floats? I'd ideally like to do this all in one line with a loop, but would also be happy setting up separate `CGFloats` for each (such as `readVol`).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Formatters in Cocoa are sensitive bastards. If it doesn't like/recognize one character of the format string, it'll just bail out and return `nil` (0, 0.0, NULL, etc.) on each call. If all you need is converting a string to a float, consider using the C stdlib function `strtod()`.

Comment: If the values are floats, why are they strings in the plist? You can put numbers in a plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` might be that it is locale
dependent. For example, with my German locale, the number `1.234,56` is converted
correctly, but `1234.56` cannot be converted.
So you could set a defined locale to solve the problem:

```
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[format setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

Alternatively, `NSString` has a `floatValue` method that gives the contents of the string
as a `float`:

```
float f = [fileArray[0] floatValue];
```

Since `CGFloat` can be `float` or `double`, depending on the architecture,
you may want to use `doubleValue` to be on the safe side:

```
CGFloat f = [fileArray[0] doubleValue];
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Going to plug this in. A CS friend suggested I google "typecasting" as well, so need to try that.

Comment: The last line, CGFloat f = [fileArray[0] doubleValue];  has worked wonders for my beleaguered final project. :-)